# Error Installing streamlit It says "ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

Tags: python, streamlit

When I try `pip install streamlit` it fails with the error message:

> ERROR: "Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

I tried installing `pip install pyarrow` directly but still gives the same error message

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback of `pip install pyarrow`? Can you also specify your operating system and version of python?

Comment: You can also try `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` and then retry `pip install streamlit`.

Answer (score 11):

In my case the problem was related to Python version. More specifically I noticed in error logs:
*RuntimeError: Not supported on 32-bit Windows*

So then I installed Python 3.8.6 (x64 version) instead of x32

[image]

and the problem was solved with

`pip install pyarrow`

Comment: u saved my life. waste too much time to tune windows python env.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced this same issue and I noted that pyarrow is a requirement in streamlit version 0.63.0. So you can use `pip install streamlit==0.62.0` and it will work just fine

Comment: While it's true that using a version of Streamlit < 0.63 will work, you'll miss out on every update from now on. For most people, they are accidentally using 32-bit Python instead of 64-bit, as https://stackoverflow.com/a/64205790/2394542 indicates

Answer (score 2):

Streamlit Version 0.62.1 and python version 3.8.5 works fine.