# I want to install streamlit but I am getting this error with the pyarrow dependences

Tags: debugging, installation, streamlit

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
  Building wheel for pyarrow (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkpasio4h'
       cwd: C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u7dfkgy9\pyarrow_98ea7953e43d453181a91fb377b77d2d
  Complete output (592 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\cffi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\compute.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\csv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\cuda.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\feather.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\filesystem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\flight.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\fs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\hdfs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\ipc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\json.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\jvm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\orc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\pandas_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\parquet.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\plasma.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\serialization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_generated_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\tests\strategies.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_adhoc_memory_leak.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_array.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_cffi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_compute.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_convert_builtin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_csv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_cuda.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_cuda_numba_interop.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_cython.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_deprecations.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_extension_type.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_feather.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_filesystem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_flight.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_fs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_gandiva.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests
  3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.testDate1900.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\decimal.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\decimal.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.all-named-index.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.column-metadata-handling.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.some-named-index.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  running build_ext
  creating C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u7dfkgy9\pyarrow_98ea7953e43d453181a91fb377b77d2d\build\temp.win32-3.8
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 204, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4dvd2f5a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 216, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4dvd2f5a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 202, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4dvd2f5a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 253, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4dvd2f5a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 589, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4dvd2f5a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4dvd2f5a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 92, in run
      self._run_cmake()
    File "setup.py", line 276, in _run_cmake
      raise RuntimeError('Not supported on 32-bit Windows')
  RuntimeError: Not supported on 32-bit Windows
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

This is the error I keep getting and I am lost at this point. I have tried reinstalling python, restarting the computer, reading other forums and I am just lost. If I could get some help on this it would be great.

However it is showing that it is installed via pip list and anaconda when checking the packages that are involved. But when I go to import the package via Vscode editor it does not register nor for atom either.

Comment: The error message "RuntimeError: Not supported on 32-bit Windows" tells you precisely what the error is. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64205790/2394542

Answer (score 1):

PyArrow need 64-bit python installation. This error shows that you have a 32-bit Python installation. Install a 64 bit version to solve this problem.

By opening python interpreter prompt you will se the version installed in your system.

```
C:\>python
Python 3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021, 13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

"`MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)`" indicates it's a 64-bit version.